# Operands for VPCMPB

Tags: assembly, x86-64, intrinsics, avx512

I see on the Intel intrinsics guide that you can use `vpcmpb` without an immediate to achieve the effect of equality comparison: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=AVX_512&expand=6816,804,804,4867,351,804,4222,914&text=vpcmpb

I try to write the following assembly instruction: `vpcmpb %zmm30, %zmm0, %k1` (g++ syntax), compare equal `zmm30` and `zmm0`, write result to `k1`. However, the assembler complains about wrong number of operands. What is going on here?

Comment: The intrinsic without the immediate is called `cmpeq`. You should use the `vpcmpeqb` instruction.

Comment: is the intrinsic reference wrong then?

Comment: The intrinsic may also be emitting the `vpcmpb` with an immediate of zero, transparently to you. Haven't checked what it does.

Comment: OK. vpcmpeqb appears to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 valid machine opcodes for doing this:

- `vpcmpeqb k, zmm, zmm`
  ([EVEX form of the MMX/SSE2/AVX2 `66 0F 74` opcode](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pcmpeqb:pcmpeqw:pcmpeqd) for `[v]pcmpeq [xy]mm, [xy]mm`.  These have never taken an immediate, with only `eq` and signed `gt` predicates being available as different opcodes)
- [`vpcmpb` or `vpcmpub`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpcmpb:vpcmpub) with immediate `0`
  (new instructions that only have EVEX forms, `EVEX.512.66.0F3A.W0 3F` or `3E`).

In asm *source*, assemblers let you use `vpcmpleb k, zmm, zmm` for example as a more meaningful way to write `vpcmpb k, z, z, 2`, as recommended in [Table 5-17](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpcmpb:vpcmpub#tbl-5-17) in Intel's vol.2 manual.  i.e. with the predicate as part of the mnemonic, implying the immediate.

That table includes a line for `VPCMPEQ* reg1, reg2, reg3` -> `VPCMP* reg1, reg2, reg3, 0`, but the shorter no-immediate form takes precedence for `vpcmpeqb k, zmm, zmm` in actual assemblers.

NASM source mixed with `objdump -S -drwC -Mintel` disassembly.  (Same results assembling with gas `.intel_syntax noprefix`):

```
                                vpcmpeqb k1, zmm0, zmm1
   0:   62 f1 7d 48 74 c9       vpcmpeqb k1,zmm0,zmm1    # 74 opcode

                                vpcmpb k1, zmm0, zmm1, 0
   6:   62 f3 7d 48 3f c9 00    vpcmpeqb k1,zmm0,zmm1    # 3f opcode

                                vpcmpequb k1, zmm0, zmm1
   d:   62 f3 7d 48 3e c9 00    vpcmpequb k1,zmm0,zmm1   # 3e opcode

                                vpcmpub k1, zmm0, zmm1, 0
  14:   62 f3 7d 48 3e c9 00    vpcmpequb k1,zmm0,zmm1   # 3e opcode
```

Interestingly, NASM/GAS will assemble `vpcmpb k1, zmm0, zmm1, 0` as written, to the form with the immediate.  But `objdump` will disassemble that back into `vpcmpeqb k1,zmm0,zmm1`, same as the no-immediate opcode, so this is one of the cases where a disassemble/reassemble round trip would change the machine code.  (But not the architectural effect of the instruction, of course)

NASM / GAS don't optimize `vpcmpequb` into `vpcmpeqb` for you, so always avoid the unsigned version when comparing for integer equality.

---

#### Errors in the intrinsics guide

If you're writing in asm, look at the asm reference manual (HTML extract https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpcmpb:vpcmpub or Intel's original PDFs that's scraped from), not the Intrinsics guide.  Especially when you run into any mystery or disagreement between what something says and what tools and/or CPUs seem to be doing!

**The intrinsics guide is certainly known to have errors** (although they do get fixed as people report them on Intel's forums).  Especially likely to see errors in the parts that aren't important for correctness of using C/C++ intrinsics.

It's not impossible for Intel's asm manuals to have errors, too, but not anything as major as leaving out an entire machine opcode form of an instruction for an already-released instruction set.

In no way is `vpcmpb k, zmm, zmm` ever valid without an explicit immediate, in real asm source or as a descriptions of machine code, so yes this is definitely an error in the intrinsics guide.

---

The `vpcmpeqb %zmm, %zmm, %k` asm syntax with reversed operand-list and `$immediate` is "AT&T syntax".  It happens to be the one GAS uses by default for `.s` / `.S` files, but you can use `.intel_syntax noprefix`.

It normally doesn't make sense to use inline asm for single instructions - compilers normally do a good enough job with intrinsics, although perhaps not always for AVX-512 mask stuff.

Comment: Yeah I thought it was weird how the opcode can optionally take an immediate. I guess it's a mistake.

Comment: However [`vpcmpeqb %zmm, %zmm, %k` actually seems to exist as a separate instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pcmpeqb:pcmpeqw:pcmpeqd). At least my version of the GNU assembler and also nasm emits that and does not support the pseudoinstructions listed in the table at all.

Comment: @Jester: Oh!  Right, my mistake, there is an AVX-512 form of that SSE2 / AVX2 `pcmpeqb` opcode.  It compares into a `k` register, so it's still equivalent to `vpcmpb` / `vpcmpub` with a `0` immediate.  So the situation isn't quite as simple.  Updated my answer to cover that.  NASM and GAS do support `vpcmpleb k1, zmm0, zmm1` for example, it's just that the shorter encoding takes precedence for `vpcmpeqb` specifically when encoding; disassembly uses the pseudo-instruction for immediate 0.

Comment: @bumpbump: see updated answer, there *is* a no-immediate form of `vpcmpeqb` (but only signed `eq` or `gt`, not other predicates).